# Problema con Collapse Sidebar menu en Vue JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, css3, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

espero esten bien, estoy tratando de hacer un sidebar menú tomandome de este ejemplo pero no me funciona...
https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index4.html He importado el codigo del demo 4 de aquí https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar pero no logro que me funcione, al menos la función de JS no logro que me tome como corresponde el collapse del menú. alguien me podría ayudar por favor:

```
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                <strong>BS</strong>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                        About
                    </a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                        Pages
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
                        Portfolio
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                        FAQ
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Minimizar menu</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SidebarMenu",
  ready: function(){
     ('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        ('#sidebar').toggleClass('active')
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

de esta manera lo que busco es que al dar click al boton de collapse me active la funcion correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Los estilos css si te los carga bien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problema solucionado, debía importar jquery en el componente, y agregar tal cual el ejemplo compartido en el link, con eso logre solucionar el collapse...

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```